# Convert text to html with streamreader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a helper that passes the path and key to look at a cshtml file.

But what it returns is the HTML but as text, so the browser is not able to compile it.

How can I write this helper to take the string and get it to a true HTML string, I've tried encoding and decoding and either I see the code, or the entities, but the browser still isn't converting it.

So what I need is @data to be HTML that get's interpreted as HTML. Is there another method of reading the file that could help?

Example code:

```
@helper readPattern(string filepath, string patternSection = null)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filepath);

    string SplitBy = "<!-- START: " + patternSection + " -->";
    string EndBy = "<!-- END: " + patternSection + " -->";
    string fullLog = tr.ReadToEnd();

    tr.Close();

    int start = fullLog.IndexOf(SplitBy);
    int end = fullLog.IndexOf(EndBy);
    int startLen = SplitBy.Length;
    int endLen = EndBy.Length;

    string data = fullLog.Substring(start + startLen, end - (start + endLen) - 2);

    @* Return Data *@

    <div data-meta="@patternSection">@data</div>
}
```

Correct Code: - Static Helper

```
@helper readPattern(string filepath, string patternSection = null)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filepath);

    string SplitBy = "<!-- START: " + patternSection + " -->";
    string EndBy = "<!-- END: " + patternSection + " -->";
    string fullLog = tr.ReadToEnd();
    tr.Close();

    int start = fullLog.IndexOf(SplitBy);
    int end = fullLog.IndexOf(EndBy);
    int startLen = SplitBy.Length;
    int endLen = EndBy.Length;

    string data = fullLog.Substring(start + startLen, end - (start + endLen) - 2);


    @* Return Data *@

    <div data-meta="@patternSection">@(new HtmlString(data))</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `@Html.Raw(value)`, which will prevent Razor from escaping it.

Comment: When I do that to the last line, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Are you in a static helpers file? If so, use `@(new HtmlString(value))`

Comment: That works. I'm new with .net, so I don't know what a static helper is.